# Android ContentResolver crash

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, telephonymanager

I am trying to capture mms events in android- I have a ContentResolver which I am setting as follows:

```
final String[] projection = new String[] { "retr_st", "date", "_id", "ct_t" };
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations");

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null,"_id DESC");
```

When the cursor is set, it with the error: FATAL EXCEPTION java.lang.NullPointerException.

This odd thing is that this works on my older versions of android, but not on the galaxy s3. SMS also seems to work fine. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:188)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
at com.onguardian.mobile.DataCollector.getMMS(DataCollector.java:116)
at com.onguardian.mobile.SentinelService.grabMMS(SentinelService.java:709)
at com.onguardian.mobile.SentinelService.access$3(SentinelService.java:700)
at com.onguardian.mobile.SentinelService$5.run(SentinelService.java:144)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you point the exact line 116 of  `DataCollector.java` and the relevant code for that line?

Comment: Line 116 is   Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null,
    "_id DESC");

Comment: Ok but where do you set the contentResolver?

Comment: ContentResolver is set in the class contructor:  contentResolver = context.getContentResolver(); (context is a parameter to the constructor)

Comment: It looks like I can set the contentResolver for sms so maybe there is a problem with the uri?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the simplfied URI as it may be looking for a database field that's not there on the Galaxy S3.

Do as follows:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
```

and if that also does not work, try to set the projection as a `"*"`, so the phone will basically query all fields available.

Comment: Looks like I was trying to access a property not available on the newer device, changed to "*" at least solved this issue.